# Как передать данные после оплаты?

Tags: json, modx

На сайте (MODX REVO) через Shopkeeper 3 оформляется заказа, при выборе онлайн оплаты пользователя перенаправляет на Яндекс.Кассу.

После успешной оплаты заказа нужно сохранять в формате JSON данные покупателя указанные при заказе, для дальнейшей передачи в кабинет пользователя.

Форма заказа оформляется через FormIt, далее данные передаются в кассу.

С онлайн платежами не приходилось работать, в каком направлении нужно искать? В API Яндекса нашел, что данные передаются в формате JSON но в Shopkeeper пользователь записывается без оплаты, а сразу после заказа.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае вы можете использовать такой workflow - писать пользователя до оплаты в заказы с флагом прошла ли оплата. В последствии проводить оплату передавая id заказа в качестве callback параметра в платежный сервисы. При успешном/неуспешном платеже платежная система делает редирект обратно на ваш сайт с параметрами, которые так же содержат данные об id заказа, данные об успешности/ошибке. получая такой callback вы можете его обработать и добавить данные об оплате в вашу БД. Не забудьте добавить поле с ошибкой платежа.
Либо добавьте таблицу платежей, которая будет связана внешний ключом с заказами и пишите данные по платежам туда. Любой платеж является асинхронным запросом, поэтому надо учитывать это при формировании взаимодействия. 
Общий flow будет таким order done -> send user to payment gateway -> payment gateway performs operations -> payment gateway redirect user with result to your system/or payment gateway calls webhook on your project with results